# Why virtual box disc can't be shrinked, when I specify the correct directory of my vm image?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, oracle

this is my virtual box installation dir.

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
```

and this one is where my image (linux.vdi) is located.

```
C:\Users\hmkhitaryan\dev\vm\linux
```

Now I want to add disc size to my vm, I did shrink it in "Virtual Media Manager", and now trying to do it in terminal, as the spec says, by this command

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\hmkhitaryan\VirtualBox VMs\linux.vdi" --resize 133672
```

and got such error

```
    C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\hmkhitaryan\dev\vm\linux\linux.vdi" --resize 133672
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to resize medium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Shrinking is not yet supported for medium 'C:\Users\hmkhitaryan\dev\vm\linux\linux.vdi'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED (0x80bb0009), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleModifyMedium(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 768 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

Anybody help me Please, what can be the reason of this error.

Comment: Is the disk dynamic?

Comment: @ajgringo619   no, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple and stated in the error message. **VirtualBox currently does not support shrinking media,** only expanding.

You can however shrink the partition inside the guest, then use [VBoxManage modifymedium --compact](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifymedium) to reduce the size of the vdi file. This will prevent it from growing bigger than your newly set partition size.

To achieve this, follow these steps:

- **Make a backup.**
- Boot the VM from an iso into a live environment (or into recovery mode and start a root shell).
- Start a partition manager, eg. [Gparted](https://gparted.org/), [GNOME Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) or use a commandline tool like `fdisk`.
- Shrink your existing partition to the desired size.
- Create a new partition after your existing ones, but do not format it into any filesystem. Make it fill the rest of the disk.
- Use `dd` to fill the new partition with zeros. For example, if you had only one disk with one partition before, the command would be: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=4M` Replace `sda2` with the newly created unused partition. You most probably have to start the command with `sudo` if not in a root shell.
- Shut down the VM.
- Locate the `VBoxManage` tool on your host machine. On Windows it is at `"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"`, open a cmd there. On *nix, it is probably on the path, so just open a terminal anywhere.
- Locate the vdi file you want to shrink. Copy the full path of it, if it contains spaces, surround with quotes (`"`).
- Compact the vdi with a command like this: `VBoxManage modifymedium --compact "c:\Users\user\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Desktop\Ubuntu Desktop.vdi"`
- This will take a few minutes on an SSD, or even hours on a HDD. At the end, your vdi file should be at most the size of your inner partition, and should never grow bigger than that.